ADF webactivity for post request 404 error
I am trying to run a post request in ADF but keep getting 404 error:
{"timestamp":"2024-05-14T19:21:44.455+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","path":"/auditlog/save"}

Activity ID
Url works fine in postman but in ADF is it giving error:
https://xyz/auditlog/save

Could it be possibly because of some access issue? I have passed in body and auth is set to none because port is open from ADF to AKS.i have also integration runtime accordingly.What else I could be missing ?

It's a 400 error, not a 404
